# Weird error "incompatible types required" when trying to make HTTP request with Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, httprequest, resttemplate

I am processing data that populates an Object (CrsApi) with all important info, URL, body params, URL params, method type. I have a collection of these and would like to just loop through and call a single method to execute each one and return the JSON Object.

From what I have googled, the best way to do this with Spring is via the RestTemplate.Exchange() function. However, it won't let me put a class in for the "Class responseType" giving me the error noted below. I don't want to have to make different specialized functions, or have to create a param specific class to hold the response.  I just want a plain Json object I can handle in a generic fashion, can I do that with this library?

```
    for(Record rec : Records){
        //Call API to update 
        CrsApi tmpApi = apiUtil.getNewApi(rec);
        handleResponse(doAPICall(tmpApi));
    }


public JSONObject doAPICall(CrsApi apiCall){
/** Handle putting on URL Parameters later **/

//---Error incompatible types required: org.json.JSONObject found: org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.json.JSONObject>
    HttpEntity<JSONObject> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<JSONObject>(apiCall.getBodyParameters());
//---
    JSONObject x = restTemplate.exchange(apiCall.getURL(), apiCall.getHttpMethod(),httpEntity, JSONObject.class);
}
```

Comment: What's the import on `JSONObject`?

Comment: org.json.JSONObject, I figured it would be a nice plain object for what I need.  We also have jackson JSONObject available though.

Comment: Are you getting compilation error? Make sure the class type is from the same import as the assigned object. Because `JSONObject` is available via many different packages, you could easily get confused.

Comment: Thats not it, I even tried explicitly putting the object "org.json.JSONObject". Also the error says its getting a "org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity <"Object Im trying to use>" I tried string, maps, etc and it always gives me that weird bit like Spring is trying to force it to be something instead of just taking the class as it is

Comment: Weird, alternatively you could also use list of maps. Like for example `List<Map<String,Object>> = template.exchange('.....',List.class)`

Comment: yea that wont work as it just says "org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity <List.class>", for some reason just just always thinks its a response entity of type T instead of the class itself...... idk.....

Comment: Well I've played with it a little more and found that it doesn't like putting it into the JSONObject "x" as the function returns a ResponseEntity<T>..

Answer (score 2):

Ha.. got it

```
    ResponseEntity<JSONObject> x = restTemplate.exchange(apiCall.getURL(), apiCall.getHttpMethod(),httpEntity, JSONObject.class);
```

I don't deal much with generic class typing.

Comment: Ha can't believe I missed that. From here on you would do 'x.getBody()' to get the JSONObject